# Electrical outlet box not flush with stone masonry

Tags: electrical, concrete, exterior, masonry

There is a crooked metal electrical box inside a stone exterior wall. There is mortar around the electric box holding it place.
I was thinking about chiseling the mortar away but I don't know which chisel would be appropriate for the task (maybe brick or masonry chisel) and I'm not sure if it would be possible.

How can I straighten my electric box so its straight and somewhat flush with the stone?

[image: crooked outlet box]

[image: outlet box not flush]

Comment: It may be intentionally tilted so that water runs out rather than in.

Comment: The problem isn't just the box not lined up with the wall surface. The receptacle is not fitting correctly in the box. Very likely that's because the original was a smaller ordinary receptacle and the GFCI is too big. In a regular wall (plaster, drywall, paneling, etc.) the solution is to cut a bigger hole and put in a bigger box. That isn't so easy here, so the solution *might* be to put the GFCI elsewhere and a slim receptacle here. **What else is on this circuit?**

Comment: 1. The outlet is mounted horizontally, so its sloped to the right.
2. The gfci fits flush with the outlet box (albeit not flush with the stone), it is just not screwed on right now as I removed the outlet cover